# How to Conditionally Create an Azure Resource-Group (or Any Resource) if Someone Else Has Not Created One

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I know that when I do terraform apply it does not deploy a resource if the previous deployment within the same terraform state, it would not re-create it .

But I want to do something different:

- Create a resource if it is not created by someone else.
- But if the resource is already there and even it is not in the terraform state, do not generate an error and have refrence to its name.

Is there any known pattern to do this?

Answer (score 2):

By design Terraform providers will typically not automatically "adopt" existing objects as now being managed by Terraform, because to do so would potentially lead to costly mistakes if you inadvertently bind a remote object to a Terraform resource and then run `terraform destroy` without realizing what is going to be destroyed.

Instead, you must bind existing objects to your Terraform resources using [the `terraform import` command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/import.html), telling Terraform explicitly that you intend it to become the sole manager of that object.